# UNNotificationContent userInfo is empty when handling response but correct when request is made

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, usernotifications

I am building a Desktop Cocoa App. When the user clicks a button, if a resource is successfully downloaded, the application sends a local notification to the user. When the user click's the notification, I want to open the URL to the source of the downloaded resource. I am attempting to store the URL in the [`userInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unmutablenotificationcontent/1649867-userinfo) dictionary in `UNMutableNotificationContent` with an integer key.

I can see that the content is there before the notification request is added: `[AnyHashable(0): "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"]`, but it is empty in the delegate's handler: `[:]`

```
// helper method to create the notification
func notify(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any] = [:]) {
  let uid = UUID().uuidString
  let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
  content.title = self.title
  content.userInfo = userInfo
  content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
  print("add notification userInfo \(content.userInfo)")
  let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
  let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uid, content: content, trigger: trigger)
  center.add(request) { (error) in
    print("add notification error \(error)")
  }
}

// notification click handler
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
  print("recieved notification userInfo: \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}
```

This is the only place notifications are being created, and I've verified that the request `identifiers` match.

#### notify() caller example

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask") {
  notificationDelegate.notify(userInfo: [0: url.absoluteString])                    
}
```

Comment: The print out in the notify function shows the userInfo correctly: `[AnyHashable(0): "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"]`, but the print out in the notification click handler shows an empty dictionary `[:]`

Comment: Is this the only place you're creating notifications? Do the request identifiers match?

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes to both of your questions. I’ve printed out the UUID during create and click and they match, but userInfo is still empty ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Bit of a stab, but try either `[NSNumber(value: 0) : url.absoluteString]` or just `["0" : url.absoluteString]` I.e., something other than a Swift `Int` for the key.

Comment: @JoshCaswell `["0": url.absoluteString]` did it. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `UNNotificationContent`'s `userInfo` property notes that the keys must be [property list types](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html). This means that they have to be one of a short list of types that are directly storable in a property list. Scalar-like types in this list include `NSNumber`, `NSString`, and `NSDate`.

The literal Swift `Int` `0` that you're using as a key **should**, as far as I know, be automatically bridged to `NSNumber` and therefore be legal as a key. It seems that is not happening.

You will have to use one of those plist types directly. If you want a number as a key, `0 as NSNumber` ought to work (hopefully?), or `NSNumber(value: 0)`. More commonly, I think, the key would be a string.

I think this is worth [filing a radar about](https://bugreport.apple.com), especially since a Swift `String` apparently *is* bridged correctly and automatically (to an `NSString`). (An exception from the ObjC side to let us know that the dictionary can't be encoded, rather than silent disappearance, would also be nice...)